# Add new user via Commerce or Add User account

Tags: commerce, users

I am working with a community site where new members should be able become members by purchasing an annual membership using commerce_license. I see 2 ways forward:

1. Members add an account application via the page .../?q=user/register and the user fills in all required fields. Via rules the appropriate membership is added, the user is redirected to the checkout, and when payment is complete the role is applied.
2. User buys the appropriate membership product, and when paid in full receives the correct role.

I have tested both these but cannot seem to get the second option working since I don't have a way to expose the custom fields added to the users, and let the user fill in those when applying for membership.

The first option seems more promising but there the user is not permitted access to the checkout page when redirected ( although I can see that the basket is created with the matching product in it).

Any pointers on how to move forward is much appreciated. I will not require an approval step, except that the membership fee must be paid in full to get access.

BR
/bo

Answer (score 0):

You can add all necessary profile fields to user register form, and disallow checkout to anonymous users. This way every time new user proceeds to checkout' they are redirected to register form where they fill in the info and then proceed with checkout as usual.

A good helper module for this is [Commerce Checkout Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect)

> This module redirects anonymous users to a page where they can login or create a new account when they try to checkout.

Comment: The site also has a webshop which permits anonymous users to purchase items. The requested logic should only apply to visitors requiring membership, so am not sure that the suggested module will help me.

Comment: details like this should be described in the question. Otherwise your question is too broad.